# How to test a debit card with not enough money on PayPal's sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I test a debit card with not enough money on PayPal's sandbox?

For example, the total amount to pay is $100 and on my credit card, I have only $5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup negative testing for that sort of a thing, and deliberately force specific error numbers you'd like to test.

Refer to Chapter 7 of the [Sandbox User Guide](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_sandbox_userguide.pdf) for more details.